# How to handle a delimiter in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

How do we handle a data in Hive when the `\t` is in the value and the delimiter is also `\t`. Suppose for example there is a column as `Street`, data type as `String` and value as `XXX\tYYY` and while creating a table we have used the field delimiter as `\t`. How will the delimiter work? In this case will the `\t` in the value will also be delimited?

Answer (score 2):

If your columns with `\t` values are enclosed by quote character like `"` the you could use [csv-serde](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) to parse the data like this:

Here is a sample dataset that I have loaded:

```
R1Col1  R1Col2  "R1Col3 MoreData"   R1Col4
R2Col2  R2Col2  "R2Col3 MoreData"   R2Col4
```

1. Register the jar from hive console

   ```
   hive> add jar /path/to/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar;
   ```
2. Create a table with the specified serde and custom properties

   ```
   hive> create table test_table(c1 string, c2 string, c3 string, c4 string)
   > row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'                
   > with serdeproperties(                                              
   >  "separatorChar" = "\t",
   >  "quoteChar"     = "\"",
   >  "escapeChar"    = "\\"
   > )   
   > stored as textfile;
   ```
3. Load your dataset into the table:

   ```
   hive> load data inpath '/path/to/file/in/hdfs' into table test_table;
   ```
4. Do a `select * from test_table` to check the results

You could download the csv-serde from [here](https://drone.io/github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde/files/target/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar).

Answer (score 1):

It will treat it as a delimiter, yes, same as if you had a semicolon ; in the value and told it to split on semicolon - when the text is scanned, it will see the character and interpret it as the edge of the field.

To get around this, I used sed to find-and-replace characters before loading it into Hive, or I created the Hive table with different delimiters, or left it at the default ^A, or \001, and then, when I extracted it, used sed on the output to replace the \001 with commas or tabs or whatever I needed. Running *sed -i 's/oldval/newval/g' file* on the command line will replace the characters in your file in place.

Is there a reason you chose to make the table with \t as the delimiter, instead of the default Hive field delimiter of ^A? Since tab is a fairly common character in text, and Hadoop/Hive is used a lot for handling text, it is tough to find a good character for delimiting.

Answer (score 0):

We have faced the same in our data load into hadoop clusters. What we did, added `\\t` whenever we saw the delimiter is included within a data fields and added the below in the table definition.

Row format delimited fields terminated by `\t`  escaped by `\\` lines terminated by `\n`